# Is there a way to view real time changes to bytes while debugging in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, debugging

I am using the X-code Version 11.3.1.

I can view the bytes by going to Debug > Debug Workflow > View Memory. However, as I make changes to the value they are not displayed unless I manually refresh the page. I want to know if there is perhaps a setting that would allow me to see the changes happen as I step through.

I also don't want to use the Watch functionality where it prints out to console if there is a change, I would prefer to watch the hex.